# В каком предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка ?

Tags: языкознание

1) По сторонам тропы высокой стеной стоял шиповник и цвёл алым и влажным цветом.
2) Лес, поле, деревня - всё посвежело после дождя.
3) В горах и в долине, и в лесу шумел неспокойный ветер.
4) Нас тесно связывали три вещи: лес, охота и любовь к литературе.

*Я убрал жирный шрифт - по глазам бьет. (b-s)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3) В горах , и в долине, и в лесу шумел неспокойный ветер. - если однородных членов с союзом "И" 2 и более и перед одним из них стоит запятая, запятая ставится и перед первым "И".